# Jboss service stop without any error in log

Tags: java, linux, jboss, redhat

Good day,

I have a service that deployed in Jboss server, OS is Linux Red Hat, in UAT environment.

For sometimes, the service will down automatically, nothing in the server.log and also application log. Memory is good enough, no out of memory issue. Actually there are many service deployed in Jboss server, but just only this specific service will down automatically without any error.

Same service war file, deployed in SIT environment, production environment, no any issue.

This issue only happen in UAT, and will happen once every month, nothing action take and later on it will become normal.

Anything I can check on this? OS log? or any other jboss log I can check?

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

`Hello`,
there are some possibilities:

1. If it was an OOM-Killer, which is a kernel process to kill an application when the memory is critically low, then you can see it in `/var/log/messages`. More information here.[enter link description here](https://docs.memset.com/other/linux-s-oom-process-killer)
2. If the JVM crashed, so then you would expect a `hs_err_pid` file, which contains the description of the JVM error. More information at [Oracle Debug.](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/felog.html#gbwcy)
3. This looks like a box issue, either memory or cpu, or a JVM issue. However, you can enable trace logs to see if there is something on the server-side, as in:

```
/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:write-attribute(name=level,value=TRACE)
```